# Python - How to regularly check if my fast-api is live?

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, endpoint

I am creating a fast-api endpoint in Docker. Do curious about how to ensure my endpoint is live?

Comment: send a request to it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you implement a `/health` endpoint that fails if the application is dead (so you usually only return a 200 OK response). If there's other reasons why your application should be considered down, you can include those as well - but be careful about what you include in the main health check endpoint.

You can also include information about the health of services you depend on, but be careful about changing the return code for those, since that may make an orchestration service (such as Kubernetes) that depend on the response from the `/health` endpoint try to restart your service - even if that doesn't help (since it's a dependency on another service, for example PostgreSQL, that's the problem). You can then get stuck in a restart loop.

If you just want something you can throw into Nagios to tell you that "oh, someone needs to check up on service xyz", make a `/health-extended` endpoint that also checks your dependencies - that way you can at least get a notice to a human when the manure hits the fan.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I think the /health endpoint is very much what I need